# How to Decode JSON object in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to decode gallery array JSON objects in Laravel 5.1. my JSON is:

```
{
  "title": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
  "category_id": "1",
  "user_id": "1",
  "gallery": "[{name: \"XCB808tvXNpqXKqekA2HlkJ8H.jpg\",size:5112},{name: \"s6kA6B0e5m1sdSAjPXqNwtiy4.jpg\", size: 13135}]"
}
```

When I use this code, return me `null`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
         $json = json_decode($request['gallery'],true);
         return $json;
    }
}
```

and this is `dd($request['gallery'])` result

```
[{'name': "XCB808tvXNpqXKqekA2HlkJ8H.jpg",'size':5112},{'name': "s6kA6B0e5m1sdSAjPXqNwtiy4.jpg", 'size': 13135}]
```

Comment: Kindly place your full code

Comment: `gallery` in not a JSON object, but list of JSON objects, so first divide them - you can use `explode()` for that.

Comment: what should I do explode ?

Comment: What is the result of `dd( $request['gallery'] )`  ?

Comment: `[{'name': "XCB808tvXNpqXKqekA2HlkJ8H.jpg",'size':5112},{'name': "s6kA6B0e5m1sdSAjPXqNwtiy4.jpg", 'size': 13135}]`

Comment: @mitkosoft: It is still a Json. No need to use explode.

Comment: @Ehsan: You should use var_dump($request); var_dump($json) ; and place some `exit`; By doing that, you will see what you are manipulating .

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant, `[{'name': "XCB808tvXNpqXKqekA2HlkJ8H.jpg",'size':5112},{'name': "s6kA6B0e5m1sdSAjPXqNwtiy4.jpg", 'size': 13135}]` is not a valid JSON object. Goto http://jsonlint.com/ and validate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The decoding process is right. I think your problem is you could have a malformed JSON string.

Replace the single quotes around property names with double quotes:

```
[{"name": "XCB808tvXNpqXKqekA2HlkJ8H.jpg","size":5112},{"name": "s6kA6B0e5m1sdSAjPXqNwtiy4.jpg", "size": 13135}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not pretty sure about your program flow but as you are injecting Request dependency to the store function, I assume the JSON object is a part of your request. In that case, you can try,

```
$input   = $request->json()->all();
```

Just print_r($input) and see what you are getting.

If JSON object is not a part of your request, you missed passing $json to your function. This is a wild guess, though!

Answer (score 1):

Just dropping by for having the same issue of trying to get the json formatted response (Laravel 8.8.0). The way I was able to get it working was using:

```
$jsonFormattedResult = json_decode ($response->content(), true);
```

Hope it helps someone out. ( '-')/

Answer (score 0):

you can use Response::json($value);